# Swift: Is it possible to create anonymous function with loop without return?

Tags: swift, closures

Let's see working example:

```
let numbers: [Int] = {
    var num:[Int] = []
    for i in 0...3{
        num.append(i)
    }
    return num
}()
```

Is there possible to avoid saving state in vars and directly return produced values?
Like in this example (I want all `i` returned in `[]`):

```
let numbers: [Int] = {
  for i in 0...3{
        i
    }
}()
```

this produces error in the last line
       `Missing return in a closure expected to return '[Int]'`

Comment: Yes, if you cange `[Int]` to `Void`

Comment: Removing `: [Int]` in first line and adding `()->() in` in line 2 helped but how I get all values produced with loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the following is sufficient:

```
let numbers = Array(0...3)
```

For general case, for example, instead of:

```
let numbers2: [String] = {
    var ret: [String] = []
    for i in 0...3 {
        ret.append(join("", Repeat(count: i, repeatedValue: "\(i)")))
    }
    return ret
}()
// -> ["", "1", "22", "333"]
```

You could use `map`:

```
let numbers: [String] = map(0...3) { i in
    join("", Repeat(count: i, repeatedValue: "\(i)"))
}
// -> ["", "1", "22", "333"]
```

Comment: Thx for answer - I have more complex problem - just made simple example for SO question:) but `map` can somehow help